# AWK read file, operate on several columns of certain lines and print all the file with the change performed

Tags: bash, awk

I want to perform some numerical changes in the file 'test'. As I did not how to do it with 'sed' I tried to do it with 'awk'. In this case, I want to multiply the numbers in the third line by certain number. The file test is described in the following:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
      0.08  0.11  0.14  0.19  0.24 TERM
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

To do it, I have done the following script 'file.awk':

```
BEGIN {}

/0.08/ {printf "      %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %s",
                      $1*var, $2*var, $3*var, $4*var, $5*var, $6;}

{print;}

END{}
```

Then I write in the command line:

```
awk -v var=2 -f file.awk test
```

The script operates on the line as I wrote, but it does replace the line.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
      0.16 0.22 0.28 0.38 0.48 TERM      0.08  0.11  0.14  0.19  0.24 TERM
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

I have read about the function sub and gsub, but despite I tried I did not succeed in replacing the old line by the new one.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The file is really 4 lines long? Is there only _one_ value to change? Or is your example just a fragment of a much more long data file?

Comment: @ Sylvain Leroux it is a fragement of a long file

Comment: Updated my post with a version that keeps the formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to step forward to the next line, otherwise the following block with the `print` statement would being executed. Use `next` like this:

```
/0.08/ {printf "      %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %s\n",
                  $1*var, $2*var, $3*var, $4*var, $5*var, $6; next}
```

Btw, `awk` is the right tool for this. There is no (reasonable) way to achieve this with sed because sed has no support for math operations.

Also note, that there are multiple ways to achieve this. Check @Jotne's answer for an alternative.

Comment: I have written the 'next' as you reccommended and kept the rest but now the program prints 3rd and 4th line in the 3rd line, giving as output: `      0.16 0.22 0.28 0.38 0.48 TERMzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`.

Comment: Oh, you missed the newline `\n` (newline) in the printf. Added it

Comment: @antoine Also note, that you can omit the empty `BEGIN` and `END` blocks.

Comment: @antoine I'm glad that I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace the field:

```
awk -v var=2 'NR==3 {$1=$1*var}1' file
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
0.16 0.11 0.14 0.19 0.24 TERM
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

---

This solution keep the formatting of the input:

```
awk 'NR==3 {f="";n=split($0,d,/[^[:space:]]*/);$1*=var;$2*=var;$3*=var;$4*=var;$5*=var;for(i=1;i<=n;i++) f=f d[i]$i;$0=f}1' var=2 t
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
      0.16  0.22  0.28  0.38  0.48 TERM
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Comment: @Jidder You do need the `-v` to read the var, or you can define the variable at the end like this: `awk 'NR==3 {$1=$1*var}1' var=2 file`  If you just remove it, this `awk` will fail and do no calculation.

Comment: Yes, i meant you could define it at the end, you could also define it within the awk statement.

Comment: @Jidder I do normal use it after the code just to save some length of the `awk`, but variable at the end can not be used in `BEGIN` block.

Comment: There isn't a begin block though ? You just seem to follow rules you've seen ,that are for specific cases, for every single script even when they are not relevant.

Comment: Initing the variables at the end reduces readability and functionality. Just always use `-v var=val` so those reading the script can see the vars being inited where they'd expect to, at the start of the script, and you dont need to think about changing how you init variables based on whether or not you need a BEGIN section or move the init if you need to add a BEGIN later. Burn up a couple more characters, live a little!

Comment: +1 for preserving the formatting. FYI an alternative way to keep the formatting is to use the 4th arg for split() in GNU awk - it lets you split the ine into 2 arrays, one of the fields and the other of the separators between the fields and then you can just operate on the fields array and print using the seps array between each field array element to rebuild the original $0. We debated the semantics of that one long and hard before getting it implemented so it'd be nice to see it used :-).

Comment: @Jotne nice to see you implemented Don Cragun's approach from here http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/249510-update-field-using-awk-keep-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jotnes answer replacing the field.

```
awk '!/08/||$1=$1*2' file
```

With a variable from shell

```
var=2;awk '!/08/||$1=$1*'"$var" file
```

If it is just the third line that needs changing

```
var=2;awk 'NR!=3||$1=$1*'"$var" file
```

Comment: You should not declare variable for `awk` this way.  Use `var=2;awk -v tmp="$var" '!/08/||$1*=tmp' file` (or at end or in BEGIN block).  And a you should also double quote variable.  And what if value is not `0.08` but `0.06` in first field? This will then fail.

Comment: @Jotne I'm basically with you, but note that `-v` isn't supported by all `awk` versions. (remembering a question related to that a couple of days ago)

Comment: @hek2mgl Can you find the version of àwk` that this does not work, or the case that this was mention?  Adding variable within the code way makes code very hard to understand.

Comment: @Jotne What is the problem with declaring the variable like this, its a number so wont contain whitespace and so doesn't need quotes, as hek2mgl said -v is not supported by all versions. And OP clearly uses 0.08 in his example, thats like me saying "what if the value is not on the third line, then yours will fail".

Comment: @Jidder I tried to find the question again, but I failed. I can only say that the conclusion of that post was "Update your awk to a recent version". Also `-v` is POSIX. So, I can't see a valid reason for not using `-v`, except of the situation where `awk` is quite outdated. In all other situations this is "bad practice". Especially not quoting the var because of assuming it *will* be a number. I've seen flying pigs! ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl All i am saying is that in this case i don't think it damages readability in any way and so using -v would just add extra uneeded code. Ill quote var then :)

Comment: Hmmm, quoting is essential and you've edited that, but I still don't think it provides *real* advantages in readability because every (experienced) awk programmer would expect variables being interpolated using `-v`

Comment: @hek2mgl I find it hilarious that "experienced" awk programmers haven't noticed that this doesnt even answer the question properly as it only multiplies the first number in the line by two,not all of them. Similar to Jotnes answer, which although it doesn't even produce the right result, is still being upvoted.

Comment: @Jidder First I attach importance on the fact that I did not used the term *experienced* in order to attack you in any way. believe me, I like the discussion. Also I did no vote so far. But yes, I've noticed that your (and Jotnes) solutions are just examples and don't provide a full solution (in contrast to my (accpted :) ) answer) ... About the topic, I would not interpolate a variable like that, but hey!, it works. So no problem

Comment: @hek2mgl okay and well done done on your answer(which i did upvote because it actually solves the problem) :) `rewrote as` your  `was spelt wrong and it was bothering me`

Comment: The only awk that does not support `-v` is old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris) which should never be used anyway. Always use `-v var=val` unless you need escapes not to be expanded and then use `'script' "val"` or you need to change initial values between files and then use `'script' var=val1 file1 var=val2 file2`. `-v var=val` at the front of the script is the clearest with the most obvious semantics way to init variables.